# Proof of Kunneth theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

What are different ways to prove Kunneth theorem relating singular homology of product space $X * Y$ in terms of homology of $X$ and $Y$? or reference?I know some ways: use cell homology for cell complex that is homotopy equivalent to original space, or similar to the proof of universal coefficient theorem. Is there any others?

Comment: Do you know any proofs at all? Have you looked at any of the standard algebraic topology texts? Without some further context or background, your question runs the risk of being closed. Read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1):

The join $X\ast Y$ is the homotopy pushout of the two projections

$$X\xleftarrow{pr_1} X\times Y\xrightarrow{pr_2} Y.$$

This lets you use a Mayer-Vietoris sequence of the form

$$\dots \xrightarrow\Delta H_{*+1}(X\ast Y)\rightarrow H_*(X\times Y)\xrightarrow{pr_{1*}-pr_{2*}}H_*(X)\oplus H_*(Y)\xrightarrow{j_{X*}+j_{Y*}}H_*(X\ast Y)\xrightarrow\Delta H_{*-1}(X\times Y)\rightarrow\dots$$

Now, inspection shows that the inclusion maps $j_X:X\rightarrow X\ast Y$ and $j_Y:Y\rightarrow X\ast Y$ are null-homotopic, so the homomorphism $j_{X\ast}+j_{Y\ast}$ is trivial and the sequence splits

$$H_*(X\times Y)\cong H_*(X)\oplus H_*(Y)\oplus H_{*+1}(X\ast Y)$$

with $H_{*+1}(X\ast Y)$ mapping onto the equaliser of $pr_{1*},pr_{2*}$.

Note the dimension shift, by the way. This makes sense since there is a homotoyp equivalence $X\ast Y\simeq \Sigma X\wedge Y$.